# Slice implementation with negative step

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

What is the start and stop value when we are doing `[::-1]` for any sequence?
I know it will reverse the string. But want to understand how it is implemented. 
`s[:]` - for this start is `0` and stop is `len(s)`.

So how is it working for `s[::-1]`

Can somebody please explain how it is implemented?

Comment: But what do you mean *"how it is implemented"*? In the CPython behind the scenes? Or if you mean why is `s[:]` equivalent to `s[0:len(s)]` then: because they're the defaults, per the spec.

Comment: I don't think that's an appropriate duplicate. This question is trying to understand the start and stop values for `::-1`. The other question doesn't say anything about that, and the obvious values don't work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if s[::-1] is reversing the string, then why s[0::-1] not reversing the string.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. I searched in stackoverflow, did not find my question. so posted it

Comment: @jonrsharpe [x:] is [x:len(s)] i think, not [x:x+1].. so s[::] and s[0::] are same. So why are they behaving different when we give a negative step.

Comment: If you give a reverse step *starting from the first character*, what's the next character? `s[-1::-1]` works, or `s[len(s)::-1]`. Please, again, [edit] to clarify what is confusing you, and spend some time reading the linked question to better understand the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of "where does it start" and "where does it stop", it starts at the last element and stops at the first. I think you knew that already, though.

In terms of "what actual start and stop values does the sequence receive", the start and stop are actually `None`. Any omitted slice argument is implicitly `None`, so

```
s[::-1]
```

is equivalent to

```
s[None:None:-1]
```

The sequence will interpret `None` appropriately depending on the slice direction.

Comment: If it is None then how it is reversing the sequence and why s[0::-1] not reversing the sequence. In stead it is giving first element as output.

Comment: @user2550098: You're telling it to start at the first character and go backwards with `s[0::-1]`. It's not going to find anything but the first character. As for how `s[::-1]` reverses it when the `start` and `stop` arguments are `None`, the sequence interprets `None` values of `start` and `stop` as starting at the last character and stopping at the first when the step is negative.